# How to fix Cygwin error on angle brackets < > in a shell script?

Tags: shell, cygwin, newline

I'm trying to get a shell script running in Cygwin and in the cut down section I posted below it crashes out with an error that reads:

new.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

usage(){
    echo "$(cat <<"EOF")"
      sh new.sh <--repo REPO>+

    --repo | -r <REPO_URL>
      url of a repository to analyze
      REQUIRES --repo OR --repo-file

    --save-credentials | -s
      save credentials (in plain text) after running

    --help | -h
      shows this message

    EOF
}
```

There are no carriage returns causing this error message. It seems its as a result of the angle brackets `<` and `>`. After removing them, it later falls over on the `(` and `)` brackets.

Is this a code issue or a Cygwin issue? Can somebody suggest a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `echo "$(cat <<"EOF")"`? Simplify: `cat <<'EOF'`

Also, the terminating EOF cannot have preceding whitespace, unless you use `<<-` and there are strictly tab characters to indent.  http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Comment: Thanks, worked. I don't really know much about shell language and didn't actually write this script I was just given the job of making it work on Cygwin in Windows. Apparently it works fine as it was in Linux.